# Stange SQL UPDATE from SELECT

Tags: mysql

Why this query:

```
UPDATE
  (SELECT A.id trophy_id
   FROM usertrophys A,
        userinfo B
   WHERE A.user_id = B.id
     AND B.cidade_new_id = 25755
     AND ban = 0
     AND A.platform = 'vita'
   ORDER BY points DESC, platinum DESC, gold DESC, silver DESC, bronze DESC, total DESC)      A
LEFT JOIN rankgeralcidade B USING (trophy_id)
SET B.rank = @r:= (@r+1)
WHERE platform = 'vita'
  AND meninas = 0
  AND cidade_id = '25755'
  AND trophy_id = B.trophy_id;</code></pre>
```

ends with this result
`select * from rankgeralcidade where cidade_id = 25755 and platform = 'vita' ;
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| id     | trophy_id | platform | user_id | rank | last_rank | best_rank | best_rank_date      | meninas | date_updated        | cidade_id |
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| 138300 |     86412 | vita     |    2774 |    1 |         1 |         1 | 2013-02-09 18:07:25 |       0 | 2012-12-25 05:20:30 |     25755 |
| 182075 |    120401 | vita     |    3546 |    2 |         0 |         0 | 2014-01-25 19:04:55 |       0 | 2014-01-25 19:04:55 |     25755 |
+--------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

when the following select have this return
`mysql> SELECT @r:= (@r+1), B.*
FROM
  (SELECT A.id trophy_id
   FROM usertrophys A,
        userinfo B
   WHERE A.user_id = B.id
     AND B.cidade_new_id = 25755
     AND ban = 0
     AND A.platform = 'vita'
   ORDER BY points DESC, platinum DESC, gold DESC, silver DESC, bronze DESC, total DESC) A
LEFT JOIN rankgeralcidade B USING (trophy_id);
+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| @r:= (@r+1) | id     | trophy_id | platform | user_id | rank | last_rank | best_rank | best_rank_date      | meninas | date_updated        | cidade_id |
+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|           1 | 182075 |    120401 | vita     |    3546 |    2 |         0 |         0 | 2014-01-25 19:04:55 |       0 | 2014-01-25 19:04:55 |     25755 |
|           2 | 138300 |     86412 | vita     |    2774 |    1 |         1 |         1 | 2013-02-09 18:07:25 |       0 | 2012-12-25 05:20:30 |     25755 |
+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

The main problem is, why the id="182075" from rankgeralcidade is updated with rank=2? 
in the same query, just replaceing UPDATE to SELECT the results seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `select` query:

```
SELECT @r:= (@r+1) as rank, B.*
FROM (SELECT A.id trophy_id
      FROM usertrophys A join
           userinfo B
           on A.user_id = B.id
     WHERE B.cidade_new_id = 25755 AND ban = 0 AND A.platform = 'vita'
     ORDER BY points DESC, platinum DESC, gold DESC, silver DESC, bronze DESC, total DESC
    ) A LEFT JOIN
    rankgeralcidade B
    USING (trophy_id);
```

The outer query has no `order by` clause.  The means that the ordering of the results is not defined.  It doesn't make a difference that you have an `order by` clause in the subquery.  *Even* if the ordering were preserved (which it is not guaranteed to be), the `join` might cause the data to be ordered in a different way.

That an `update` and `select` would produce different orderings makes perfect sense to me.

If you want a stable assignment of values, then use `order by` clauses on the outermost queries, for both `select` and `order by`.

EDIT:

I didn't realize that MySQL doesn't support the `order by` with the `join` (because I don't use `order by` on updates very much).  You can still do this with a subquery:

```
update rankgeralcidade b join
       (<the select query here>
       ) toupdate
       on b.trophy_id = toupdate.trophy_id
    set B.rank = toupdate.rank;
```

Comment: Why are you doing a left outer join and then only selecting rows from the second table?  If there is no match, then they will be `NULL`.

Comment: adding ORDER BY cause "Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY"